# server-server receipt validation vs online validation from device to apple for subscriptions

Tags: ios, https, man-in-the-middle

I am researching what's the best way to do a subscription validation without making users login.
I read
`Apple doesn’t recommend Online validation because of security reasons: HTTPS request can be intercepted via man-in-the-middle attack.` (Source - https://blog.apphud.com/receipt-validation/)

This has me thoroughly confused. Does apple not force HSTS so the receipt validation is open to man-in-the-middle attacks?

What's the best way to do a no-login receipt validation on iPhone apps for subscriptions?  If I do server-server without login, then won't sending my back-end be susceptible to hackers just spoofing a userId?

Comment: HSTS won't help you, because the risk comes from the fact that you don't control the iOS device.  The user can MITM or even completely spoof Apple's receipt validation server.  The "bad actor" here is not some attacker on the Internet, it is the device owner.  If you rely on your own server for validation then there is still some risk that the response can be spoofed, but you can include a digital signature in your server response which now requires a code-level as well as a network level attack

Comment: Thanks - but won't my app have the same code-level verification?

Comment: No, the difference is between getting a yes/no answer from Apple's server  (which uses a well-known and documented format) vs getting a yes/no answer from your server which you control and you can build more verification and security. It is still possible for people to spoof or attack the process but you have made it a lot harder.